# Is there any other way except URL parameters to filter views in tableau

Tags: filter, query-string, tableau-api

I want to pass parameters to tableau to filter views. Parameter values can be quite long . Since there are limits imposed by browsers and servers on URL, cannot pass  these parameters in query string.
Is there any alternative way ?
Tableau version is 8.1

Please help

Comment: Use Javascript Api. They help u filter with lots of options. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/help.htm#js_api.htm

Answer (score 0):

@Vivek
Thanks for your response. I don't want to use javascript API since that would require a lot of changes in my app. So i'm thinking of joining tables and making use of user filters to achieve the same